# Should I wait until my performance review to quit?

Tags: quitting

My annual review is next week, but I intended to quit my job this week. **Should I wait until the review to tell my boss or just go through with it this week?**

I've decided to quit mainly because of family commitments. My mother recently passed away and I'm split between my father's and my apartment dealing with probate matters. I've decided to go back to school and I don't have time to handle the estate stuff, never mind make time to finish an application. I've recently found a remote gig that will give me more flexibility and time to focus on myself. To be honest, I've been planning to quit for weeks and I'm ready to leave tomorrow.

I'm expecting to hear that I'm getting a raise in my review and that I've done a fairly good job. My manager is more big picture and generally isn't that harsh, because our team does mostly self-guided projects. I'm nervous about quitting mostly because I do genuinely love my job and the people I work with. My manager was very supportive when I lost my mom and gave me more extra time off to deal with the funeral. Basically, I know it's time to go but I'm sad about it and don't want to make things more awkward before I go.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question? Why have you decided to quit? What do you expect to hear in the review? Is there a reason you would choose to delay quitting?

Comment: @Jay Just edited to add more details

Comment: You say you love your job and have a good boss, would working part time be a solution (for you) instead of quitting? If working part time is a solution then you could talk about the in your performance review.

Answer (score 5):

Are you certain you are going to quit, irrespective of the outcome of the performance review, or any potential raise/promotions offered?

If yes, you can do it as per your convenience (as soon as possible could be one of the options). In fact, doing it before the review meeting would be less awkward in my opinion, as the management won't assume that a (possibly) bad review is the reason for you to quit. Quitting before the review would be the way to go, as there won't be any review meeting to worry about!

If no, wait till the review meeting and think again based on the outcome of the meeting.

You have nothing to lose either way. The former however would be less awkward.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I'm very sure that I am quitting and I don't care either way how the performance review goes. I'm just hesitant to go into the review and then turn it into me quitting, which is what I imagine happening.

Comment: @Maggie Quitting before the review would be the way to go. That way there won't be any review meeting to worry about!

Comment: @NimeshNeema maybe not as if then OP gets a raise any pay during the notice will be at a higher rate or if there are any voluntary redundancy schemes you might lose out.

Comment: @Neuromancer While your point is valid, money may not be the motivator for everyone, all the time. OP appears to be concerned about having a sound decision and looking to avoid any awkward situations.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I do just want to leave on good terms and not offend my boss in the manner that I'm quitting. The money would be good (and I know I'll prob get a raise) but I'm more concerned about having more time to deal with my family and personal life right now before I make other career moves.

Comment: @Maggie It would certainly make this easy for both you and your employer if you mention that personal life and family time is a priority and that's the reason for your move.

Answer (score 1):

Making a decision to quit is usually (hopefully) the result of having exhausted all other approaches to dealing with issues in your job, whatever they may be. The important implication for your situation is: would the performance review influence your decision? If no, then it should not play a role in choosing when you notify your employer of your decision.

Given that, if you feel you're at the point where you've decided to quit, and you have a date in mind that you'd like for your last day, the standard practice is to inform your employer of your decision based on any required notification period. In other words, if you have a two week notice period, you should alert your boss two weeks prior to your desired last date.

If you know you want to quit, and your notification period is 2 weeks, but you want to keep working for several months, you should wait until 2 weeks before your desired last day (versus telling your boss now, for instance). Telling your boss too far ahead of your desired last day can result in issues - your boss may treat you poorly, or look for a reason to lay you off immediately.

If you know you want to quit, but don't have a particular last day in mind, you should base your decision on whatever factors you know about your future plans - if you're interviewing for other positions and hope to move immediately into another job, the standard advice is to **wait until you have accepted another written offer** before quitting. You generally don't want to quit without another job lined up, if your intention is to keep working.

Notice that none of these if - then statements are based on the date of your performance review. You should inform your boss based on the timeline that's best *for you* - if you've made up your mind to quit, waiting until the performance review won't likely make anything less stressful or change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're due for an annual raise after the performance review, waiting until after will let you report a higher salary in job interviews.