# I quit, and boss offered me 3 month "grace period" where I could still come back

Tags: resignation

There was a recent death in my family and I need more time to focus on my mental health & family, so I tried to quit my job. I had already taken a 2 month leave of absence earlier in the year and returned to work, but things haven't gotten better and I decided to leave and move back home to spend more time with my family.

When I went to quit, my boss offered me a 3 month "grace period" where we would meet again and I could get my job back if I wanted it. I figure I have nothing to lose? He's drafting up a contract to make it official that I'm leaving and that we'll revisit this in 3 months. I think he doesn't want me to quit or thinks that I will change my mind, but I feel like I've moved on and want to pursue other opportunities.

Has anyone ever had this happen to them? I plan on waiting out the 3 months and just letting him know that I won't be back for real, but I'm worried there will be something weird in the contract? Is anything about this situation sketchy or will be bad for me in the long term? Any suggestions for how to handle this?

UPDATE: Thank you to all who have answered! I've looked at the contract now and it's an extended leave of absence form. I'm very hesitant to sign it because one of the conditions is a non-compete, where I can't work or do business in any capacity or solicit work from the company's existing clients. I understand the non-compete part but this section is worded like I can't find any work at all? I would like a clean break, so this seems like a red flag. Am I reading too much into it? Is it worth having a lawyer look over?

Comment: Outside of the death in your family, were there things you didn't like about the job, enough to make you want to leave anyways? It sounds like that may be the case but it might be worth making it more clear.

Comment: What's your location?  In the US, for example, I think such contracts would be fairly "weightless" with the labor laws that exist.

Comment: It's probably not valuable for us to try and speculate about what the negative consequences of the contract may be without seeing it.

Comment: If you are concerned about the contract then you should have a lawyer specializing in labor law in your country review it.

Comment: Without more details I would say he does want to give you a chance to change your mind and at the same time doesn't want to keep your position open indefinitely.

Comment: You typically don't need to sign a contract to quit a job.

Comment: "I'm worried there will be something weird in the contract" - you'll only know the answer to that once you get the contract, and then you'd need a lawyer if you're still not sure.

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139575/should-i-wait-until-my-performance-review-to-quit where the asker contemplates the decision to leave and its timing

Comment: It sounds like a different wording for an unpaid leave.

Comment: What contract? You have not shared it, so no one can speculate on its terms or their weirdness.

Comment: @L.Dutch It might be an unpaid leave at the end of the day.

Comment: I'd take this as a compliment. In my experience, unusual retention efforts like this are a sign that you're viewed by your management as someone who provides exceptional business value to the company. **Make certain to maintain this relationship in your professional network after you leave**, because this kind of job reference for future employers is gold. If you're ready to leave the company, then it doesn't really matter what the contract says, right? And you would have seen huge red flags already if there were shenanigans. If you're ready to move on, thank your boss and politely decline.

Comment: If you need any advice or just talking about it i am right now in a complicated long grief that has kept me from working for months, i just recently started again, somewhere else. my email is on my profile.

Comment: Must be nice to have this kind of job security.

Comment: Hi, thank you everyone's answers! i apologize for not returning sooner to the thread but I finally got the contract. It is an unpaid leave contract, but I feel fairly confident that I won't return so I'm very hesitant to sign this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware of the type of contract you are given. Signing a temporary leave might mean having to come back and give the notice period 3 months from now. I was in a very similar place two years ago, where my team lead tried to convince me into not giving notice before holidays, and coming back for a month more.

Fortunately, as they say, several heads think better than one, and while tempted, several friends advised me on not taking the "offer", e.g. cutting the cord and go on a care free holidays without having worries when coming back.

It was one of the best free advice people ever gave me. It allowed me to put all that behind my back, focus in myself, my wife and our holidays. More importantly, it allowed to completely close and turn my mind off about a chapter of my life, and move on. It also allowed me to not carry my mobile number in roaming to be there for them.

Whilst it seems a security blanket, do you want to be on call, own them something, or have that in the back of the mind for three more months?

PS Off-topic: I also had un unplanned bonus at the end of the fiscal year, the tax return for not working 1.5 months was roughly around the same amount I would have had gained if I had returned for that month.

Answer (score 254):

It seems to me that your boss believes the reasons you are leaving are entirely about you: your loss, your grief, your health. Your boss hopes that in a few months, these reasons will change leaving you back where you were before the loss: liking your job and happy to do it.

If you have information that your boss doesn't (actually I was getting pretty fed up of the job anyway before this happened, or just being in the building reminds me of those awful times) then you **could** spare them the trouble of writing up an official "permission to re-apply" contract by being honest now and then just walking away. But since your boss is making this offer, I'd say let it happen. Focus on yourself and your recovery for 3 months. Don't look for other jobs. Relax, get better.

About two months from now, when you think about returning to work, will you dread it? Does looking for jobs and going to interviews feel like a horrible burden or an exciting opportunity? Does it feel like a "safety net" to know your old job is waiting for you, or an anchor, or what? As the three-month mark appears will you be worried?

If knowing your old job is waiting means "I will have money and a place to go and people I already know" then that's a good thing. Your boss is offering you that. If it means "I owe an obligation to people I want nothing to do with" then that's not so good. You are unlikely to know which it is (because it's a mix of the two) until closer to that three month mark.

As for "hitches" or "catches" in this "contract" it doesn't sound like any are planned and in many jurisdictions they are not legally possible. The real reason for declining now instead of 3 months from now is to be nice to someone who is going out on a limb for you. The real reason for waiting is that a person who is unable to work due to grief and other issues is often also unable to make the right long term decisions: knowing that, it's wise to avoid long term decisions that don't have to be made immediately.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. There's no downside to the contract, only possible upside for OP.

Comment: Some companies offer unpaid "leaves of absence" for employees who need a little time for health reasons, to take care of a family issue, etc.  It sounds like your boss is trying to offer you something like that, even though it might not be on the company's "official" benefits list.

Comment: The last sentence is key here, and in addition the employer is attempting to reduce the impending stress when the OP decides they are ready to work again. In the meantime, they will likely hire a temp-worker on a 3 to 6 month contract and after the discussion in 3 months time, will extend or not extend a permanent offer to the temp worker depending on the discussion outcome.

Comment: This is a very good answer.  It highlights that the boss is offering a slight alternative to a full resignation (for 3 months at least).  However, only you can judge your mental health, and what your state it might be in 3 months from now.

Answer (score 40):

Be grateful for the opportunity. It seems your boss is really valuing your work. Do not dismiss this opportunity right now. Wait the three months and see where you are then. You can always decide after three months to not return.

> I'm worried there will be something weird in the contract?

If the wording of the contract is unclear, or if you are afraid it makes you promise something you cannot deliver, have a lawyer look at it. If you are a union member, they may provide job related legal counsel for free, or for a reduced fee.

Answer (score 17):

One possible reason for the formal contract could be that your boss is not sure if he is going to be in the company in three months. If he i still there when you return, he could just give you a new contract but if he leaves, his promise will just be forgotten and he cannot help you anymore. By giving you a contract, he makes the promise official and binds the company to it.

Comment: Not in the real world. An everyday manager won't have the power to bind a company to take the employee back - in most jurisdictions today the concept does not even exist for regular employees.  But a contract can (and sadly often does) have terms which purport to limit the employee's future flexibility, and there's nothing to be gained by renewing those.  It's at best no better than an expression of being open to reconnecting, and at worst something with terms that could prevent the asker from taking a future job, that unlike this one, they actually want.

Comment: It could be implemented as a normal contract that starts in three months and with the option for the employee to terminate the contract without repercussions. He is also talking about his 'boss' so I'm not sure where your 'everyday manager' comes from.

Comment: You forget that the employee **does not want the job**.  The chances that having the paper will force a later unwilling company to give them a job that turns out to be a positive experience *that the actually want* are far lower than the certainty that evaluating a contract now is an unwelcome burden and the real chance that it could have terms that limit a different job the employee actually wants.  If it's legit it doesn't need to be signed *now*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: if the manager has the authority to sign a regular employment contract, he has the authority to sign one with a few unusual wrinkles. While the contract won’t guarantee a job, regardless of whether the manager is still there or not, it will make it a bit more likely.

Comment: @jmoreno - Actual employment contracts binding on the company are not an ordinary thing in much of the world today - in such places, where they occur *at all* they would be uniquely negotiated at C level or more likely by the board in consultation with the lawyers.  What the asker gets is likely to be only thinly modified boilerplate that in practice gives them almost nothing actually enforceable, but may have boilerplate terms that heavily limit their own options for future jobs.  They already do not want to return, they'll certainly not want to return to a company that no longer wants them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Maybe you should consider that the US is not the same as the world. Is is possible that you have no employee rights whatsoever, but there are other parts (hint: those with working health care), in which these contracts are perfectly normal. Greetings from Germany :)

Comment: You're still overlooking that **the employee does not want the job**, and even if they change their mind and the *unspecified* jurisdiction is one where they could force the company to take them back, **working at a place you have to force to hire you will be unpleasant**.  The chances that actually signing this will be in their favor vs. merely taking it under consideration are low: the fact that evaluating the fine print right now is an undesired burden is certain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The legality of a contract drawn up by a specific manager at a specific company is in no way dependent on how common such contracts are in general. Weird one-off contracts are signed all the time, being unusual doesn't make it any less binding.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, "Actual employment contracts binding on the company are not an ordinary thing in much of the world today" -- Mm..., doesn't employment usually bind the company to stuff like paying a particular salary at a particular time of month? Not having some sort of a contract for that would seem a bit odd, but maybe I'm being eurocentric here. Do you have a citation for that "not in much of the world" claim?

Comment: @ilkkachu - being owed compensation for the work you do is a very distinct thing from a promise that your job will be ongoing, or in this case that it would be waiting months in the future

Comment: @barbecue - its not about legality but about authorization and enforceability.  An everyday manager won't have the authority to create something that isn't 99% boilerplate, and that boilerplate will be so chock full of terms and loopholes heavily in favor of the company that regardless of the present manager's intent the employee is not likely to have any enforceable future guarantee in practice.  Sadly the boilerplate is also likely to have terms which limit the employee's options - which is not a good bargain **when they've made it very clear they DO NOT WANT the job**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton your broad sweeping claims are simply untrue. It's easy to find counter-examples of managers offering contracts to employees, and contracts being offered without the involvement of boards or attorneys. I'm not saying you're wrong about how things should be, I'm saying you're wrong about how they actually are in reality.

Comment: Nope.  A contract an ordinary manager could issue would be, as I specifically explained, 99% prewritten boilerplate pre-approved by legal and thus containing all the usual loopholes.  And it would still be a contract related to **a job the asker DOES NOT Want** .

Answer (score 11):

I quit a job of 5 years and moved out of state.  My company had never hired a person working out of state to work remote because it is a state funded agency and that's frowned upon. Five weeks later my former boss and I had a meeting and he outlined a proposal he would make to the powers that be... seven weeks later mountains had moved and I had my laptop delivered by FedEx.

All this to say - LOOK - when you're good at what you do the regular rules of employment don't always apply.  Obviously - you were an asset to this company, your boss, and the other employees.  They don't want to lose you and realize that you need some personal time due to some catastrophic events.

So take your time, enjoy it, and re-evaluate in 3 months.

Comment: Indeed, no reason to burn bridges.  But also **absolutely not reason to sign anything!**   If the offer is legitimate, it is legit without a signature.  And if it isn't, a bullet best dodged.

Comment: "enjoy it"? Maybe not the best wording

Answer (score 8):

> Any suggestions for how to handle this?

Just resign from the company and don't sign any contract.  Since you do not plan on returning to the company there is no need to give your boss the impression that you will return.  Your statements below indicate that you are not going to return:

> I think he doesn't want me to quit or thinks that I will change my mind, but I feel like I've moved on and want to pursue other opportunities.

And:

> I plan on waiting out the 3 months and just letting him know that I won't be back for real

You need to be upfront with your boss and let him know that you will not return.  It is clear that the boss sees value in you if he wants to retain you as an employee but if you do not want to be there it makes no sense to pretend for three months.  Thank your boss for the offer and your time with the company and move on.  It is the best choice for all parties.

Comment: The boss is fully aware that he might not come back and is providing him with an alternative. There is no harm to either party in waiting the three months, while there  is a clear downside for the OP if he changes his mind in two months. Situations change on a dime, the more options you have, the better.

Comment: +1 on not signing anything.  There's absolutely nothing to be gained from that, and not even any *legitimate* benefit to the company, so a request to do so would be an immediate red flag.  But there's also no need to burn any bridges.  Feelings could change - don't lead the boss on about likelihood of returning, but there's no need to absolutely rule it out as long as its been clear that it is not your plan

Answer (score 4):

Not something I've heard of happening before - could be a nice gesture, or it could have strings attached (especially since there's a legal contract he wants you to sign.) Difficult for us to say from the question, so I'd definitely exercise caution.

If you don't want to sign anything, and don't think it's something you'd use in any case, but appreciate the offer, then I'd just say:

> Thanks, I really appreciate that. However, can we just keep it as an informal arrangement which we can use if necessary rather than getting into contractuals?

Comment: The contract could possibly be for the OPs peace of mind rather than the employer.

Comment: @Bee "I think he doesn't want me to quit or thinks that I will change my mind, but I feel like I've moved on and want to pursue other opportunities." <- doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Worth noting that that is the OPs interpretation about the situation. You'll also notice I wasn't disagreeing with you, only adding another perspective

Comment: It may not be clear to the boss that the OP is adamant to never return. As @Bee said, the boss may be doing what he believes is supporting the OP.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Boss seems like he thinks he's supporting OP through this difficult time.

Comment: When a siilar situation was presented to me, it was for buying them time to find a suitable candidate.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has happened to me once some years ago. I was employed full time working for a large multinational, based in Northern Virginia, near Washing DC. My wife was accepted into a graduate program abroad (in UK) and I decided to move with her. I wasn't sure how things would work out in the UK, so it was great when I was offered a similar 3-months "grace period". Essentially, within 3 months they would take me back for the same role with the same salary.

I ended up not needing it - and I'm still in the UK 16 years later.

Answer (score -3):

**DO NOT SIGN ANY SORT OF CONTRACT FOR SOMETHING YOU DO NOT EVEN WANT**

If this is a legitimate, well intentioned offer to consider taking you back, then there's absolutely no way that benefits from your signature.  A willingness to consider taking you back is just that - a *willingness* - and it's only practically meaningful if at a future time both you and the employer end up interested in pursuing it.

In the meantime, any insistence on your signature is a serious red flag - there's nothing to be gained by *binding* yourself to this employer you are presently determined to leave, or them to you in a way that you would be unable to enforce or enjoy anyway.  If they want to list conditions that limit the situations in which they would take you back, they are free to do so *unilaterally*.  But put simply, if they are honest about having your mutual best interest in mind, they will be able to understand from a single, polite objection why it is pointless for you to sign anything, and accept your refusal.  If they push the issue, it indicates there's something more going on - either a shady purpose, or a serious failure of understanding.  In either case, that would be a sign that it is time to disengage even more actively than you had already been planning to.

**Best case** - they make the offer, you say "thank you, I will keep this in mind" and in a few months you feel better, reach out and they take you back.

**Intermediate case** - one party ends up interested in renewing the relationship, the other is not, so nothing happens - but that is also for the best, because **trying to use a previous agreement to force employment when either party is unwilling will not be a positive outcome**

**Worst case** - they do not have your best interest in mind, and leaving them behind with no remaining ties was the right choice.

(For that matter, unless you are being given something *new* of *useful value* in return, you should not sign any sort of agreement, acknowledgement, or *anything* beyond the letter of resignation comprising your own words when leaving a position.  Any terms or restrictions you were previously bound by do not need another signature; anything you were not previously subject to is definitely not an obligation to take on when there is no longer anything to be gained in return for doing so.  People may make bogus arguments why you should, but these are empty - they are still obligated to provide your final paycheck without delay)

Comment: Did you read the original post? He talked about "I could get my job back if I wanted it" and not " A willingness to consider taking you back". And the option to get your job back is definitely something useful.

Comment: @FooTheBar - there's no practical difference - the possibility is ultimately no more than a possibility.  Anything that purports to be a promise would be so full of loopholes as to be unenforceable on the company, nevermind the cost of trying.  And in most jurisdictions today, the concept of promised employment does not even exist, at least not in the way that an ordinary mid-level manager could bind a company to.  The reality is that it's at best an offer to consider; but it could have terms which cost the employee flexibility in what they chose to do next.

Comment: "the concept of promised employment does not even exist" How would you call a working contract with non-immediate starting date?

Comment: "Working contracts" do not exist in much of the world today, except for unusual cases like high level executives, sports talent, etc.  Pretty much everyone else could be arbitrarily back on the street without explanation five minutes after being hired, and is only protected from being dismissed for specific illegal reasons, which they would have the difficulty of demonstrating were the actual motivation.

Comment: By "much of the world today" you mean "USA"?

Comment: The asker's word choice in this and their previous question is in general more consistent with places where employment contracts are not generally used, than it is with places where they are

Comment: That doesn't change the generality of you comments.

Comment: I think this answer is a little too concerned that there will be something nefarious in the contract. 

While it—and all other contracts—should be read carefully, it's also possible this "contract" will just clarify a few fairly mundane things: when/how you need to notify them about your decision, whether vacation time and seniority will accrue during this gap if you return, the status of your health insurance and other benefits, and so on.